# Visual Studio showing only one code suggestion?

Tags: unity, visual-studio

I'm on visual studio 2022 (not visual studio code) for unity, and for some reason, visual studio will only display one suggestion, and asks me to press Alt+. to see the next one. IntelliSense is installed and I have:

- checked preferences
- Tried to resize the box with the mouse
- Browsed the internet

How do I fix this? If it's a design choice, it's a very bad one. I want to get the dropdown that shows me all of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it after one more hour of browsing:
Visual studio doesn't like it when you change Program Files (x86) directories to other drives